# Mongodb/Mongoose : create two types of models for user accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose in  nodejs and I'm looking for some suggestions on a MongoDB schema to have two types of users : employee and client, both of them will use the same registration page(I'm using passport for the authentication).

I'm thinking of having one commun Account model (for employee and client) which will contain some commun stuff like email,pass,name etc, and then embedding Account shema in Employee and Client models.

I'm not sure if if it's the right way to do it, so any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since both `employee` and `client` has many common properties and has few specialized properties. So, IMHO, it would be better to make a single schema for them.

```
var Person = new Schema({
    type: String,
    // common properties below
    email: String,
    dob: String,
    // props of employee
    joiningDate: Date,
    // props of client
    account: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed }
});
```

Here, you can segregate the `Client` and `Employee` on the basis of `type`

Comment: and  could I just dynamically specified the account schema each time a user want to register ? if he registers as client I'll user  account:{type: Schema.Types.Mixed ,ref: client } and same thing with employee